# C++ class not found on SWIG interface

Tags: java, c++, swig

Good morning everyone,

I'm finding trouble to make a SWIG interface work for C++. I have several .cpp and .h files, of all of them I only want to create an interface for a few (which I will use in my Java code), hence my .i file looks like:

```
/* File : AlgoritmoElectrico.i */
%module alg

/* Header files that are referred in the ones I want to create the interface with */
%{
#include "AlgoritmoElectrico.h"
#include "Proyecto.h"
#include "Indice.h"

/* ... I skipped a few to make it shorter ... */

#include "ParserTime.h"
%}

/* Header files of classes I want to use in Java */
%include "AlgoritmoElectrico.h"
%include "AlgoritmoElectrico.h"
```

So I ran `swig -c++ -java AlgoritmoElectrico.i` and got several .java files, plus the .cxx wrapper, I compiled all the .java files with `javac *.java` and created the .so library with the native and wrapper code.

My Java code looks like this:

```
package mr;

/* ... Stuff ... */

public class MRAlgoritmo {

    public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> {
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // Obtiene instante y circulaciones
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\t[ ||| ]"); // FIXME revisar regex
            String[] info = pattern.split(value.toString());

            // Captura datos de proyecto
            System.loadLibrary("algoritmo");
            Proyecto proyecto = new Proyecto("Proyecto1");
            proyecto.ReadFile("infraestructura");
            proyecto.getParametros().setIntervalo(1);

            // Ejecuta algortimo con datos de circulaciones
            AlgoritmoElectrico algoritmo = new AlgoritmoElectrico(proyecto);
            String [] resultados = algoritmo.Ejecutar(info);

            /* ... stuff ... */
        }    
    } 



     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        /* ... stuff not related with the above, working with Hadoop MR ... */
     }

}
```

`Proyecto` and `AlgoritmoElectrico` are C++ classes and they are not being found. Ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, it was a packaging error. I forced swig to add a package statement to the .java files and then the import worked fine

I used `swig -c++ -java -package <package_name> <files>`, then I compiled and built the jar preserving the package structure. After that I could refer to its contents as usual and it worked fine.